# Android: Avoiding top popup blocks taps on screen

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, android-popupwindow

I have a broadcastReceiver which creates a popup on top of all of apps using WindowManager.

I got this working but the problem now is when the popup is opened it's impossible to tap on the activities which are on the back of the popup. it's felt like there is a big transparent view or something.

The code of the BroadcastReceiver is:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static String TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";
private String number;
// private CustomDialog dialog;
private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
private PhoneStateListener listener;
private Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE));
    Log.i(TAG, intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER));
    createOverlay(context);
}

public void createOverlay(Context context) {
    final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    final View customView;
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            200,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );
    params.height = 200;
    params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    customView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.caller_popup,null);
    ImageButton closeButton = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.ib_close);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            wm.removeViewImmediate(customView);
        }
    });
    wm.addView(customView, params);

}
```

}

and the layout file is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_custom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="#ab2fc4"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_close"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a sample popup window."
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="25sp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` to the flags you're passing as the fourth argument in the `WindowManager.LayoutParams` constructor call.

Comment: It works!! thanks a lot @MikeM.